# Number of ordered pairs dividing 720

Tags: number-theory

How many ordered pairs of natural numbers like $(a,b)$ exists such that $a$ and $b$ divide 720 but $ab$ doesn't?

my own idea was to solve in two cases: 1.a==b and 2.a!=b

I found answer 24 pairs for part 1 but I don't know how to solve part 2.

Comment: Looking at prime decompositions is often a good idea. Described in terms of prime decompositions, what would make a number divide $720$? What would make a product of such numbers _not_ divide $720$?

Answer (score 1):

The OP's idea of splitting into two case (which, if I interpret the OP's notation correctly, are $a=b$ and $a\not=b$) is OK, but unnecessary. Here's an alternative approach:

$720=2^4\cdot3^2\cdot5$ has $(4+1)(2+1)(1+1)=30$ divisors, so there are $30^2=900$ pairs of divisors $(a,b)$ altogether.  The "live" question is how many ways can you take each divisor of $720$ and split it into two pieces, $a$ and $b$? The total of these numbers will count the number of pairs of divisors whose product is still a divisor; the number we want will be the difference from $900$.

Now if your divisor is $2^r\cdot3^s\cdot5^t$ with $0\le r\le4$, $0\le s\le2$ and $0\le t\le1$, you have $(r+1)(s+1)(t+1)$ ways to do the split.  Thus the total number of pairs who product *does* divide $720$ is

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=0}^4\sum_{s=0}^2\sum_{t=0}^1(r+1)(s+1)(t+1)
&=\left(\sum_{r=0}^4(r+1) \right)\left(\sum_{s=0}^2(s+1) \right)\left(\sum_{t=0}^1(t+1) \right)\\
&=(1+2+3+4+5)(1+2+3)(1+2)\\
&=15\cdot6\cdot3\\
&=270
\end{align}$$

and therefore the number of pairs of divisors whose product does *not* divide $720$ is

$$900-270=630$$

Comment: @DavidK, ah, you are right. I misunderstood what the $24$ referred to.  I thought it was the number of *all* pairs of equal divisors (which is just the number of divisors).  I'll delete that parenthetical remark. Thank you for pointing it out.